# Environment requirement for human life

Tags: human-biology, environment

I was wondering, what are the humans needs to fulfill to achieve a human colonisation on mars ?

Let me explain, this is for role play game in a futuristic world where humans colonized mars.
That creates questions that needs answers for background purposes. 
I saw like each another some scifi, read novels etc. But I'd like to know scientifically what could help us achieve that.

If this post doesnt have it's place here, do not hesitate to remove it.

In my mind : 
breath
eat
drink
dont take radiations (at least not to much)
stay at the right pressure and temperature
any gravity issue on our body ?
try to avoid wandering naked in space

Any help is appreciated 
thanks guys :)

Comment: This would be more appropriate someplace like Worldbuilding.SE, it isn't really about biology per se. From a biology standpoint, it is under researched for the standards of Biology.SE.

Answer (score 1):

[**Here**](https://settlement.arc.nasa.gov/75SummerStudy/Chapt3.html) is a good write-up for NASA of human needs in space, which applies to other planets, too.

[**Here**](https://settlement.arc.nasa.gov/75SummerStudy/Table_of_Contents1.html) is a table of contents with links to chapters that discuss relevant information for you.

The source is described so:

> Space Settlements: A Design Study, provides information on space
>   settlement development and education and assists teachers and students
>   in the NASA Ames Space Settlement Design Contest. The design study was
>   the result of a 10 week program in engineering systems design held at
>   Stanford University and Ames Research Center in the summer of 1975.
>   Participants included professors, technical directors and students in
>   a variety of disciplines from physical science and architecture to
>   engineering and social science. The goal (see preface) was to
>   construct a vision of how people might sustain life in space in a
>   large colony.